# Mac keeps SMB files/session open, locking files

Tags: finder, sharing, smb, file-sharing

This is very frustrating. I open a Windows SMB share like this:

[image]

After closing the window, my Mac kept folder/files open and I had to close the SMB session from the server.

How do I just close all open SMB sessions on my Mac?

Comment: Hello red888, welcome to Ask Different. Closing the Finder window is not enough to stop the SMB session. You need to eject the server. To do that, select the server icon on the desktop and press Command-E. Could you try that and report back?

Comment: thats the answer i wanted

Comment: Great! I've added it as an answer. Tomorrow I'll add a screenshot ( I don't have access to any SMB share now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing the Finder window is not enough to stop the [SMB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) session. You need to eject the SMB share in the same way you eject external drives or a CD/DVD, that is, **select the SMB share icon on the desktop and press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>.**

Alternatively, you can right-click the SMB share icon and select *Eject* :

[image]

or, in a Finder window, press the eject button next to the server name:

[image]